# Differentiate between MS personal and business account

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I have two microsoft email's. One is personal account and other is business account. Using microsoft graph API/ azure endpoint(since I am authenticating users using azure) is it possible to identify the type of account associated with the email.

Comment: First of all make sure you're using the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint, since ```By using the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint, you can create apps that accept both work and school (Azure Active Directory) as well as personal (Microsoft account) identities.```

Comment: Yes I am using Azure v2.0 to authenticate the users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `tenant ID`.

> **Taken from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens)**:
>   A GUID that represents the Azure AD tenant that the user is from. For work and school accounts, the GUID is the immutable tenant ID of the organization that the user belongs to. For personal (Microsoft) accounts, the value is 9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad. The profile scope is required in order to receive this claim.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)